# Combinatorics - find $n!$ using inclusion-exclusion

Tags: combinatorics, factorial, inclusion-exclusion

difficult question I need help with.

We are asked to show that $n! = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^n$

There is also a hint "try to think of the number of permutations of n elements using inclusion-exclusion"

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591350/difference-of-powers/594462