# Expression for $\sum_n n^a/n!$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm wondering if there is a general solution for $$S_a =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^a}{n!}$$ with $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a > 0$.
From Mathematica:
$$S_1 = 1e$$
$$S_2 = 2e$$
$$S_3 = 5e$$
$$S_4 = 15e$$
$$S_5 = 52e$$
$$S_6 = 203e$$

Comment: You may be interested in this: http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C5%2C15%2C52%2C203&language=english&go=Search

Comment: It might work better if you compute $S_a(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^a}{n!}x^n$. (I haven't tried, so maybe it doesn't help.)

Comment: $S_0$ is in line with the sequence Antonio points to as well.

Comment: @DanielFischer Your suggestion would appear to help, consult this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972868/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Dobinski's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobinski's_formula) for [Bell numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614786) for more information.