# Evaluation of a finite sum

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I am having trouble evaluating the following finite sum:

$$
\sum_{l=0}^{r}\binom{r}{l}(r-l)^{k},\qquad k\in\mathbb{N}_{0}.
$$

Can you shed light on it?

Comment: Are you be able to evaluate $\sum_{l=0}^r {r\choose l} l^k$?

Comment: Yes... this finite sum involves Stirling numbers...

Comment: Ok great. Because it's the same sum!

Comment: Wow, it's true! What a silly question I have posted! Thank you :)

Comment: Resembles http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591350/factorial-as-difference-of-powers-sum-r-0n-binomnr-1rl-rn-n