# Combinatorial proof of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}(l-k)^n=n!$, using inclusion-exclusion

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorial-proofs

If $l$ and $n$ are any positive integers, is there a  proof of the identity

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}(l-k)^n=n!\;$$

**which uses the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle?**

(If necessary, restrict to the case where $l\ge n$.)

---

This question is closely related to [Expressing a factorial as difference of powers: $\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}(-1)^r(l-r)^n=n!$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591350)

and also [Proof of the summation $n!=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(n-k+1)^n(-1)^k$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861402)

Comment: Have you read the answers to the linked question?  http://math.stackexchange.com/a/591361/312

Comment: @leonbloy I did look at all of them, but I didn't see an answer which proved this identity for every positive integer l using Inclusion-Exclusion (although one of the answers treats the case $l=n$).

Comment: The identity is only true for $l=n$, no?

Comment: @leonbloy The OP seems to indicate this, but I believe the answers given by Marko Riedel and robjohn show that it's true for any positive integer $l$.

Comment: Indeed, Marko Riedel's and robjohn's answers prove it for any $l$. I won't close as duplicate since you want inclusion-exclusion-- also an enthusiastic +1 for including the linked questions :)

Comment: I added some emphasis to make clear the difference between this and linked questions, and cleaned up a couple of things. Don't use displaystyle in titles, and in posts it's usually better to just use double dollar signs.

Comment: @6005 Thank you for the edits, and for the advice about when to use displaystyle .  (I was wondering about using it in the title, after I saw how it looked.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume that $\ell\ge n$. We want to count the injections from $[n]$ to $[\ell]$ whose range is $[n]$. For each $k\in[n]$ let $A_k$ be the set of functions from $[n]$ to $[\ell]\setminus\{k\}$. It’s not hard to see that for any non-empty $I\subseteq[n]$ we have

$$\left|\,\bigcap_{k\in I}A_k\,\right|=(\ell-|I|)^n\;,$$

so by the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Statement) we have

$$\begin{align*}\left|\,\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k\,\right|&=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[n]}(-1)^{|I|-1}(\ell-|I|)^n\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}k(-1)^{k-1}(\ell-k)^n\;.
\end{align*}$$

This is the number of functions from $[n]$ to $[\ell]$ that miss at least one element of $[n]$, so we want the size of the complementary set, which is

$$\begin{align*}
\ell^n-\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}k(-1)^{k-1}(\ell-k)^n&=(-1)^0\binom{n}0(\ell-0)^n+\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k(\ell-k)^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k(\ell-k)^n\;.
\end{align*}$$

Of course there are $n!$ injections from $[n]$ to $[\ell]$ with range $[n]$, so

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k(\ell-k)^n=n!\tag{1}$$

for $\ell\ge n$.

Let

$$p(x)=n!-\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k(x-k)^n\;;$$

$p(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $n$, and every integer $\ell\ge n$ is a zero of $p(x)$, so $p(x)$ must be constant, and therefore

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k(x-k)^n=n!$$

for all $x$: $x$ need not even be an integer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer -- this generalizes the results of the two linked questions.

Comment: @MontyHall: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\{1,\cdots,n\}$ and $B=\{1,\cdots,l\}$ where $l\ge n$, and let $S$ be the set of functions from $A$ to $B$.

If $E_i$ is the set of functions in $S$ which do not have the value $i$ for $1\le i\le n$,

then $\overline{E_1}\cap\cdots\cap\overline{E_n}$ is the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ which have $A$ as their range.

Using Inclusion-Exclusion,

$\displaystyle|\overline{E_1}\cap\cdots\cap\overline{E_n}|=|S|-\sum_{i}|E_i|+\sum_{i<j}|E_i\cap E_j|-\sum_{i<j<k}|E_i\cap E_j\cap E_k|+\cdots$

so $\;\displaystyle n!=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}(l-k)^{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I am providing an answer here as the original post I had wrote it in (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3486057/proving-sumk-n-0-frack-nk-1nk-nn-1)) was made a duplicate of this post. As such, I reference this post (as in the exact page you the reader are on right now) in my answer. I believe my answer is sufficiently different to warrant this however as I expand on the question and provide an interesting approach using analysis. Here is my answer to the other question in full

---

We will prove something stronger. Namely, that

$$f_k(x)=\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{(k+x-n)^k(-1)^n}{(k-n)!n!}=1$$

for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. However, first we will provide a lemma that will be used later in the proof. That is that identity

$$\sum_{n=0}^k\binom{k}{n}n^j(-1)^n=0\text{ for }0\leq j<k$$

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Explicit_formula), an explicit formula for Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind is

$$S2(j,k)=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{n=0}^k(-1)^{k-n}\binom{k}{n}n^j$$

Then

$$\sum_{n=0}^k\binom{k}{n}n^j(-1)^n=k!(-1)^kS2(j,k)$$

However, $S2(j,k)$ is defined as the number of ways to arrange $j$ elements into $k$ non-empty sets. The key here being non-empty. That is, if $j<k$ then it is impossible to arrange the $j$ elements into $k$ non-empty sets so $S2(j,k)=0$. That is, if $j<k$ then

$$\sum_{n=0}^k\binom{k}{n}n^j(-1)^n=0$$

Having proved our lemma, we continue onto the main proof. Now, consider the form of $f_k(x)$. Obviously, $f_k(x)$ is a polynomial. That is, it is an entire function. We are justified then in taking its [Maclaurin Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html). To this end, we need to calculate $f_k^{(m)}(0)$ for $m\geq 1$. Now, since $f_k(x)$ is of degree at most $k$, $f_k^{(m)}(0)=0$ for $m\geq k+1$. Consider the derivatives of $f_k(x)$:

$$f_k^{(0)}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{(-1)^n (k-n+x)^k}{n! (k-n)!}$$

$$f_k^{(1)}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{k (-1)^n (k-n+x)^{k-1}}{n! (k-n)!}$$

$$f_k^{(2)}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{(k-1) k (-1)^n (k-n+x)^{k-2}}{n! (k-n)!}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$f_k^{(m)}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{k! (-1)^n (k-n+x)^{k-m}}{n! (k-n)!(k-m)!}$$

for $0\leq m\leq k$. Thus,

$$f_k^{(m)}(0)=\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{k! (-1)^n (k-n)^{k-m}}{n! (k-n)!(k-m)!}$$

$$=\frac{1}{(k-m)!}\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{k! (-1)^n (k-n)^{k-m}}{n! (k-n)!}$$

Expanding $(k-n)^{k-m}$ in its [Binomial Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) gives us

$$=\frac{1}{(k-m)!}\sum_{n=0}^k\left[\binom{k}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{k-m}\binom{k-m}{j}k^{k-m-j}n^j(-1)^{n+j}\right]$$

Since these are finite sums, we can switch the order of summation to get

$$=\frac{1}{(k-m)!}\sum_{j=0}^{k-m}\left[ \binom{k-m}{j}k^{k-m-j}(-1)^n\sum_{n=0}^{k}\binom{k}{n}n^j(-1)^{j}\right]$$

But for $m\geq 1$, $j$ will always be less than $k$. This is precisely the lemma we proved above. Thus, for $m\geq 1$

$$=\frac{1}{(k-m)!}\sum_{j=0}^{k-m}\left[ \binom{k-m}{j}k^{k-m-j}(-1)^n\cdot 0\right]=0$$

and hence

$$f_k^{m}(0)=0$$

Since every coefficient in the Maclaurin Series except for the $m=0$ is zero, we conclude $f_k(x)$ is a constant function. That is

$$f_k(x)=a_k$$

where $a_k$ could change depending on $k$. We seek to show that $a_k=1$ for all $k$. In fact, this is easily done as we can simply calculate $f_k(0)$:

$$f_k(0)=\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{(k-n)^k(-1)^n}{(k-n)!n!}=a_k$$

(this is your original question). In fact, these terms can be rearrange to

$$a_k=\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{(k-n)^k(-1)^n}{(k-n)!n!}=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{k!(k-n)^k(-1)^n}{(k-n)!n!}$$

$$k!a_k=\sum_{n=0}^k\binom{k}{n}(k-n)^k(-1)^n$$

However, as was pointed out by user @Angela_Richardson, this exact problem can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862571/combinatorial-proof-of-sum-k-0n-1k-binomnkl-kn-n-using-inc) already. In the link provided, simply swap $n$ and $k$, and set $l=k$ to get

$$k!a_k=\sum_{n=0}^k\binom{k}{n}(k-n)^k(-1)^n=k!$$

$$a_k=1$$

Thus, your original question is answered in the affirmative as well as

$$f_k(x)=\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{(k+x-n)^k(-1)^n}{(k-n)!n!}=1$$

for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.