# Finite Sum evaluation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, summation, riemann-sum

Can anyone help me in proving the following identity: For any $k\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^n(k-n)^{2k}}{n!(2k-n)!}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
Thank You very much in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to show us what you have tried.

Comment: Seems like you should try induction

Answer (score 1):

Note that by letting $m=2k-n$ we get
$$\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^n(k-n)^{2k}}{n!(2k-n)!}=\sum_{m=k}^{2k}\frac{(-1)^{m}(k-m)^{2k}}{(2k-m)!(m)!}$$
Hence
$$\frac{1}{(2k)!}\sum_{n=0}^{2k}(-1)^n\binom{2k}{n}(k-n)^{2k}=\sum_{n=0}^{2k}\frac{(-1)^n(k-n)^{2k}}{n!(2k-n)!}=2\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^n(k-n)^{2k}}{n!(2k-n)!}.$$
So it suffices to show that (in our case $j=2k$, and $x=k$)
$$\sum_{n=0}^{j}(-1)^n\binom{j}{n}(x-n)^{j}=j!$$
This is a well known identity:

1) [Combinatorial proof of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}(l-k)^n=n!$, using inclusion-exclusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862571/combinatorial-proof-of-sum-k-0n-1k-binomnkl-kn-n-using-inc)

2) [Expressing a factorial as difference of powers: $\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}(-1)^r(l-r)^n=n!$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591350/expressing-a-factorial-as-difference-of-powers-sum-r-0n-binomnr-1)

Comment: I got the first line clearly, but not the second line. Why the second line is sufficient? Can you elaborate please? Thanks...

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: Clear, but how to prove the last equality? I can take $x=\frac{j}{2}$. Then how to proceed? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @Mathlover See the references

Comment: where are the references?

Comment: ok, let me see. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We use the  *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
n![z^n]e^{kz}=k^n\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain (interchanging $k$ and $n$ for convenience only)
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n}&\color{blue}{(-1)^k\frac{(n-k)^{2n}}{k!(2n-k)!}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\frac{k^{2n}}{(n-k)!(n+k)!}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(2n)!}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{2n}{n-k}k^{2n}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2(2n)!}\sum_{k=-n}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{2n}{n-k}k^{2n}\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2(2n)!}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^k\binom{2n}{k}(k-n)^{2n}\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^k\binom{2n}{k}[z^{2n}]e^{(k-n)z}\tag{6}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}[z^{2n}]e^{-nz}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}(-e^z)^k\tag{7}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}[z^{2n}]e^{-nz}(1-e^z)^{2n}\tag{8}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}[z^{0}]e^{-nz}\tag{9}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2}}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we exchange the order of summation $k\to n-k$.
- In (3) we use the binomial coefficient notation.
- In (4) we observe that each summand is symmetric with respect to $k$ and we use this property to sum the half of the summands from $-n$ to $n$.
- In (5) we shift the index to start from $k=0$ and use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (6) we apply the *coefficient of* operator according to (1).
- In (7) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and do some arrangements as preparation for the next step.
- In (8) we use the binomial theorem.
- In (9) we note that $[z^{2n}](1-e^z)^{2n}=[z^{2n}](z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\cdots)^{2n}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\left.S_{k} \equiv
> \sum_{n = 0}^{k}{\pars{-1}^{n}\pars{k - n}^{2k} \over
> n!\pars{2k - n}!}\right\vert_{\ k\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 1}} =
> {1 \over 2}:\ {\Large ?}}$.
>   
>   Note that
>   $\ds{S_{k} \equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\color{red}{k}}{\pars{-1}^{n}\pars{k - n}^{2k} \over n!\pars{2k - n}!} =
> {1 \over \pars{2k}!}\sum_{n = 0}^{\color{red}{k - 1}}
> {2k \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}\pars{k - n}^{2k}\
> \mbox{with}\ \color{red}{k} \geq 2}$.

For $\ds{\color{red}{k} = 1}$, the sum $\ds{S_{1}}$ is already equal to $\ds{\large{1 \over 2}}$ !!!.

---

$$
\mbox{Note that}\quad\bbx{%
\sum_{n = 0}^{k - 1}{\pars{-1}^{n}\pars{k - n}^{2k} \over n!\pars{2k - n}!} =
{1 \over 2}\sum_{n = 0}^{2k}{\pars{-1}^{n}\pars{k - n}^{2k} \over
n!\pars{2k - n}!}}
$$

---

\begin{align}
&\sum_{n = 0}^{k - 1}{\pars{-1}^{n}\pars{k - n}^{2k} \over n!\pars{2k - n}!} =
{1 \over 2\pars{2k}!}\sum_{n = 0}^{2k}{2k \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}
\bracks{\pars{2k}!\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\expo{\pars{n - k}z} \over z^{2k + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
{\expo{-kz} \over z^{2k + 1}}\sum_{n = 0}^{2k}{2k \choose n}\pars{-\expo{z}}^{n}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
{1 \over 2}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
{\expo{-kz} \over z^{2k + 1}}\pars{1 - \expo{z}}^{2k}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
{\expo{-kz} \over z^{2k + 1}}\bracks{\pars{2k}!\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{n \brace 2k}{z^{n} \over n!}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=
{\pars{2k}! \over 2}\sum_{n = 2k}^{\infty}
{n \brace 2k}{1 \over n!}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
{\expo{-kz} \over z^{2k - n + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\pars{2k}! \over 2}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{n + 2k \brace 2k}{1 \over \pars{n + 2k}!}{\pars{-kz}^{-n} \over \pars{-n}!} =
\left.{\pars{2k}! \over 2}
{n + 2k \brace 2k}{1 \over \pars{n + 2k}!}{\pars{-kz}^{-n} \over \pars{-n}!}
\right\vert_{\ n\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] = & \bbx{1 \over 2}
\end{align}