# Structure of $x^n$ - what is this called?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, power-series, exponentiation, factorial

Is there a write up on the following somewhere? I don't know what to call it and have not found anything online for it. I had worked this out in school as an attempt on Fermat's Last Theorem. I revisited it recently to see if it had other uses.

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc|c|cccc|c|ccccc}
x^3&&&&x^4&&&&&x^5&&&&&&\\
0&&&&0&&&&&0&&&&&\\
1&1&&&1&1&&&&1&1&&&&\\
8&7&6&&16&15&14&&&32&31&30\\
27&19&12&6&81&65&50&36&&243&211&180&150\\
64&37&18&6&256&175&110&60&24&1024&781&570&390&240\\
125&61&24&6&625&369&194&84&24&3125&2101&1320&750&360&120\\
216&91&30&6&1296&671&302&108&24&7776&4651&2550&1230&480&120\\
343&127&36&6&2401&1105&434&132&24&16807&9031&4380&1830&600&120\\
\end{array}
$$

This is how its constructed, (quite easy to do on a spreadsheet),

1. The first columns, under $x^n$, are just that for $x = 0 ... 7$
2. Subsequent columns hold the difference, from the previous column, between  the values in the current row and row above it

The leading edge, last column values, ($k_x$),
where $x \ge n$, works out to,
$k_x = n! = {n \choose 0}x^n - {n \choose 1}(x-1)^n + {n \choose 2}(x-2)^n … - {n \choose n-1}(x - (n-1))^n + {n \choose n}(x-n)^n$

$k_x = n! = \sum_{y=0}^n (-1)^y {n\choose y} (x-y)^n$

where $x < n$,
$k_x = {x \choose 0}x^n - {x \choose 1}(x-1)^n + {x \choose 2}(x-2)^n … - {x \choose x-1}(x - (n-1))^n + {x \choose x}(x-n)^n$

$k_x = \sum_{y=0}^x (-1)^y {x\choose y} (x-y)^n$

The above holds for all $x$ and $n$, even $n=2$, i.e. all of them form a ladder till $x=n$ and then the subsequent $x^n$ are formed by adding the sum of an arithmetic sequence, with difference $n!$  to $x^{n-1}$

The case for $x \ge n$ is known and proven. It is covered in other [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591350/expressing-a-factorial-as-difference-of-powers-sum-r-0n-binomnr-1) on this forum so I won't repeat it here. The case for $x<n$ follows once $x \ge n$ is established.

I'd like to know what this is called and if there is any analysis on this I can read up. I maybe wrong but to me it has a few possibilities, e.g.

1. For equations of degree 3, 4 or higher it one could reduce the terms to a quadratic or cubic equation, as these are essentially sums of series
2. The above could also simplify higher degree residues/reciprocity equations/calculations.

Answer (score 2):

For a sequence $a_n$, the values $s_n = a_{n+1} - a_n$ are commonly called the (forward) differences, and $s_n = a_{n} - a_{n-1}$ are the (backward) differences. Another keyphrase: "[finite difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference)".

The terminology and theory of differences has a lot of parallels with the theory of differentiation. E.g.

- One derives algebraic rules for computing differences
- One talks of solving difference equations (or the closely related recurrence relations)
- One exploits interpretation of summation as the anti-difference
- There is a Newton series for reconstructing the value of a function from its differences

As a guess, I googled the term [difference table](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DifferenceTable.html) and got hits, so I guess that's a standard term for the entire table of differences you are constructing.

Answer (score 0):

Mean value theorem gives you exactly what you are observing.