# Is the following an acceptable formal proof for $0! = 1$?

Tags: proof-verification, factorial

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591350/expressing-a-factorial-as-difference-of-powers-sum-r-0n-binomnr-1), we can write factorial as successive differences.

Can I use that for proving **$0! = 1$** formally

The formula is as follows

> $$\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}(-1)^r(l-r)^n=n!$$

$l$ is any integer (don't take as zero in the below example)

Note that $r$ can be any initial value other than zero also. I am taking it as one.

Now, if I substitute $n=0$, then

> $$0! = \sum_{r=0}^{0}\binom{n}{r}(-1)^r(l-r)^n = \binom{0}{0}(-1)^0 (l-0)^0 = 1(1)(1) = 1$$

Comment: What is $l$ in your question?

Comment: @HanulJeon edited and is detailed in referred question.

Comment: Thanks, i am in another world... @Henry

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing you can prove about $0!$ before you have defined it. The formula that you mentioned assumes that $n!$ is defined, for every non-negative $n$.

Answer (score 2):

But you're still making the assumption that $$\binom 00=\frac{0!}{0!0!}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a formal proof that uses [the gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

> The gamma function is defined as $$\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!\tag{1}$$ where $n$ is a positive integer and $$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}\,dx\tag{2}$$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with a positive real part.

Now consider $z=1$. From $(2)$, we have $$\Gamma(1)=\int_0^\infty x^0e^{-x}\,dx=[-e^{-x}]_0^\infty=1$$ and substituting this into $(1)$ we get that $$0!=1$$