# Proving $\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}j^{n-2}(-1)^{n-j+1} = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

> Prove
> $$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}j^{n-2}(-1)^{n-j+1} = 0$$

My wrong proof try is this:

$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}j^{n-2}(-1)^{n-j+1} = \sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}1^jj^{n-2}(-1)^{n-j}(-1) 
=-\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}1^j(-1)^{n-j}j^{n-2}$

We know:

$(\forall x,y \in R)(\forall n \in N) (x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k}$

Therefore:

$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}1^j(-1)^{n-j} = (1-1)^n = 0$

And

$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}1^j(-1)^{n-j}j^{n-2} \leq \sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}1^j(-1)^{n-j}n^{n-2} \\
= n^{n-2}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}1^j(-1)^{n-j} \\
= 0$

And

$
\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}1^j(-1)^{n-j}j^{n-2} 
= \sum_{j=1}^{n}\binom{n}{j}1^j(-1)^{n-j}j^{n-2} \\
\geq \sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}1^j(-1)^{n-j}1^{n-2} \\
= 1\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}1^j(-1)^{n-j} \\
= 0$

Therefore

$0 \leq \sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}1^j(-1)^{n-j}j^{n-2} \leq 0 \Rightarrow \\
\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}1^j(-1)^{n-j}j^{n-2} = 0$

And

$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}j^{n-2}(-1)^{n-j+1} = 0$

I later realised that the comparison cant be made due to the $(-1)^n$

I have also tried by testing for n even and odd numbers. I can prove it for odd numbers but not for even.

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: The expression equals 1 when n=2, so it’s untrue in general. Are you sure there are no conditions on n?

Comment: Yes I have noticed that, and yes there are no conditions, our prof is not that great so stuff like that are to be expected from us unfortunately.

Comment: You can use an inclusion-exclusion argument as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852540/find-sum-m-0n-1m-mn-n-choose-m/1853581#1853581): the general problem in that question is the same as yours up to a factor of $-1$ when $r=n-2$. Basically you’re just showing that there are no surjections from $[n-2]$ to $[n]$.

Answer (score 3):

I fully expect this will be marked a duplicate since it has appeared so many times. We have

$$\sum_{j=0}^n {n\choose j} j^{n-2} (-1)^{n-j}
= (n-2)! [z^{n-2}] \sum_{j=0}^n {n\choose j} \exp(jz) (-1)^{n-j}
\\ = (n-2)! [z^{n-2}] (\exp(z)-1)^n.$$

Now since $\exp(z)-1 = z + \cdots$ we obtain $(\exp(z)-1)^n = z^n + \cdots$ so that $(n-2)! [z^{n-2}] (\exp(z)-1)^n = (n-2)! [z^{n-2}] (z^n+\cdots) = 0.$ This is for $n\ge 2.$

Comment: That first equality is rather nonobvious.

Comment: It is just $j^m = m! [z^m] \exp(jz).$

Comment: I don't really get the first equality? Is it based on some identity property or something?

Comment: This is a coefficient extractor from [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Ah, that coefficient extraction operator is a notation I'm not familiar with. Might want to make a note of it.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel, Thank you a lot, but unfortunately we have not yet been taught that yet. Could you please direct me to another solution, or the logic behind it?

Comment: @jimangel2001 The following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3918408/) has two additional answers as well as additional links.